# Confusion about calculating first order correction to energy eigenstate / state vector

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, potential, perturbation-theory, eigenvalue

I am trying to determine the first order correction to the ground state for a particle in an infinite square well with a given perturbation,
$$V'(x) = \frac{2\pi^2 h^2}{mL^3} (\epsilon x- \frac{\epsilon L}{2});  \frac{L}{2} \le x \le L$$
$$ V'(x) = \infty; x \lt 0, x \gt L $$
$$ V'(x) = 0, 0 \le x \lt \frac{L}{2} $$
And $$ V_0(x) = 0; 0 \le x \le L $$
$$ V_0(x) = \infty; else. $$

I already know that the "0th order" states and energies are 
$$ | n^0> = \phi_n^0 = \sqrt{\frac{2}{L}}sin(\frac{n\pi x}{L})$$
$$ E_n^0 = \frac{n^2 \pi^2 h^2}{2mL^2} $$
And I already found the first order corrections to the ground and first excited state energies by using the following equation:
$$ E_n^1 = \int_{L/2}^L (\phi_n^0)^2*V'(x) dx $$
(because there are no complex components to $ \phi_n^0 $)

(h here is hbar, reduced Planck's constant)

Now I am trying to find the first order correction to the ground state itself and I am confused on how to do this. I know that the first order correction to a state is given by [image]

but I don't understand how to use it in this context. What is "m" in this situation? I think I understand where m and n come from when the perturbation is written in matrix form, but I'm stumped in this situation. Can this not be used because m=n? Is there another more applicable expression in integral form with only one state "n", and not "m"? I cannot find any other expression for the first order correction to a state. Any help is appreciated here, and thank you in advance!

Comment: You already, correctly, found $ |  n^0\rangle$ where $n=1,2,...$. does it make any difference if you call $m$ or $n$ the variable over which you are summing? Note that you should also compute the matrix elements $ {H'}_{m,n}$.

Comment: @lcv Yes, I'm confused on what my value(s) of m would be (because you are summing where m is not equal to n, but I'm only interested in one state). Would the matrix elements just be the integral of the "zeroth order" state n multiplied by V'(x) and the zeroth state m in this case?

Comment: 1) you have to compute corrections to the GS. So what is $n$ corresponding to the GS? Then you sum over all $m$ different from it. 2) the matrix elements are just particular scalar products. So yes, except that $n$ is fixed (to be the GS value)

Comment: @underpressure yes. You will have to integrate from $l/2$ to $l$, that is the space where the potential exists.

Comment: BTW I only noted now. Why you're integrating over this funny range? PS @ManvendraSomvanshi : No.

Comment: @lcv That was the range mentioned by the OP in which the potential exists.

Comment: @lcv Yes, I understand that now - I was just confused on which m I need to use. It is an infinite sum given that there are infinite states... Is it safe to assume that using only one term, m=1st excited state, is a "good enough" approximation? And I am integrating over L/2 to L because that's the only region where there is perturbation.

Comment: 1) no it's not safe. Compute the matrix elements correctly and you will see that things will simplify. 2) why that? Do you know what is the definition of the scalar product? Use that definition. Then ask yourself better what are the unperturbed eigenfunctions. What is their value when the variable $x$ ranges over the whole line?

Comment: @ManvendraSomvanshi yes sorry, I missed that but that's not 100% right. The perturbation is non zero also in other regions yet there is another reason why you don't integrate over those regions.

Comment: 2') yes that region is correct. Do you really know why?

Comment: @lcv I cannot practically compute this as an infinite sum over all states from m=2 to infinity... I have the correct expression for the unperturbed eigenfunctions written above in the question, no?

Comment: Underpressure Why not? Yes but you also have to compute the matrix elements ${H'}_{n,m}$

Comment: @lcv The matrix elements will be computed in the sum from m=2 to infinity of the integral of (unpert. eigenfunc. m squared)*(unpert. eigenfunc. n)*V'(x) dx, why would I have to compute them separately?

Comment: 1) at some point you will have to compute them, no? 2) Your expression for the matrix element is wrong. Why the square? 3) Is this homework?

Comment: @lcv No, that is not the expression for a single matrix element. I'm saying that I don't need to separately compute the matrix elements because that calculation is taken care of in the expression above, which is for the first order correction to the state n (I didn't include the denominator, though, because I was only referring to the integrated portion). The square comes from the 'bra' of unperturbed m state and 'ket' of unperturbed m state in the formula for 1st order state correction. This just becomes the state function m squared because there are no complex components.

Comment: @lcv I have done examples in the past in situations where there are infinite states but I did not need to compute the sum to infinity, but only do a few explicit calculations for a few m states. And more typically the context I have been working in before involved a set, small number of states (like a spin-1 particle, with states 0, -1, and +1, where you only need to compute the correction to state n=0 for states m=1 and m=-1). The example I gave is a homework problem, but I was confused in general about the use of the expression for the first order correction to the state in similar cases.